# How can one invest in bismuth?

Tags: precious-metals

How can one invest in [bismuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bismuth) without actually buying it?

Are there futures that can be bought or an ETF that tracks the price?

There are only about six Olympic-size swimming pools of bismuth on the planet — twice as much as the total amount of gold.  Gold trades at $1,250 per ounce while bismuth trades at $10 per pound.  I know people like gold more but bismuth could become more popular in the future.

Comment: Without buying it, you'd have to look for a company that mines it, and buy that stock.  (Not an Answer, since there might be some better way.)

Comment: Given the small size of the world market, it is highly unlikely that there are mining companies that derive all or a majority of their revenues from bismuth production, i.e. there are no "pure plays". Even if such companies do exist, they might be privately owned or government owned.

Comment: @njuffa: Sounds right; Wikipedia says "Bismuth has always been produced mainly as a byproduct of lead refining".

Comment: There was [Auzex Resources Ltd.](https://www.bloomberg.com/research/stocks/private/snapshot.asp?privcapId=23886764), acquired by Bullabulling Gold Ltd., acquired by Norton Gold Fields, acquired by Zijin Mining Group.  That one you can trade (2899 HK) but 70% of their turnover is from precious metals.

Answer (score 2):

As of Dec 2017, there are 4 major spot markets: Rotterdam, USA (New York), India and China.  Argus covers all of them, Platts covers New York.

Currently, there are no futures based on any of the indices.  There are no ETFs tracking any of the indices.  There are no ETCs.

There was a company, Kingsgate Molybdenum/Bismuth Mine Ltd., later [Auzex Res Ltd.](https://www.bloomberg.com/research/stocks/private/snapshot.asp?privcapId=23886764), that had started out with a molybdenum/bismuth mine in Eastern Australia but they soon diversified into gold and precious metals.

Then there is [Hunan JinWang Bismuth Industry Co Ltd](http://en.jin-wang.com.cn/gywm.html) but they're mostly about refining and research.

Source: Bloomberg security finder (SECF).